# Error finding data with cakephp

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

When I try to find a given users's posts (in UsersController), I get the following error "Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Posts.user_id' in 'where clause'" . 
Here's the profile function

```
public function profile($id = null) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (!$this->User->exists()) {  //if the user doesn't exist while on view.ctp, throw error message
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
    }
    $this->set('user', $this->User->read(null, $id)); //sends info to view.ctp. 
    $conditions = array('posts.user_id' => $id);
    $this->set('posts', $this->User->Posts->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions)));
```

}
This is the query.

```
 SQL Query: SELECT `Post`.`id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`body`, `Post`.`created`, `Post`.`modified`, `Post`.`user_id` FROM `blog`.`posts` AS `Post` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1
```

**EDIT - I got the query to work, now I'm having another issue**

On my profile.ctp page I get the following error

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP/View/Users/profile.ctp, line 35]
```

This is line 35

```
 <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
```

Here is the statement from profile function in the UsersController

```
$this->set('posts', $this->User->Posts->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions)));
```

Comment: Do you have a `hasMany` association from `User` to `Post`? If so, you should be using `$this->User->Post->find`.

Comment: Have you set up your models? what do your model files look like? You need to specify the relationship between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `Post` model *belongs to* `User` and `User` *has many* `Post`, modify your code to be:

```
$this->set('posts', $this->User->Post->find('all',array('conditions' => $conditions)));
```

Comment: I checked what you suggested and now I'm getting the following error "Call to a member function find() on a non-object"

Comment: As noted, I made some assumptions. Can you verify those? Also, I pluralized `Post` on accident. See update. It's late :)

Comment: I updated my original post to show my UsersController hasMany relationship

Comment: Got it to work, had to change a couple things - updates above